# Page refreshing after pressing button in selenium?

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

Hi i have this code with tries many number on yahoo after the button of submitting is clicked
the page seems to get refreshed because i am not able to press the same button.

here is my code

```
import os
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import filedialog
import selenium
import time
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import Select
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium import webdriver
import contextlib as textmanager
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

PATH= "C:\chromedrivers\chromedriver.exe"
driver= webdriver.Chrome(PATH)

list=[]
file= open("numbers.txt", "r")

for line in file:
        line = line.strip() #preprocess line
        list.append(line)






driver.get("https://www.yahoo.com/")



element = WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//*[@id='consent-page']/div/div/div/form/div[2]/div[2]/button")))

element.click();

time.sleep(1)

sign_in= driver.find_element_by_xpath("//*[@id='ybar-inner-wrap']/div[3]/div/div[3]/div[1]/div/a").click()
time.sleep(1)
forgot_phone= driver.find_element_by_xpath("//*[@id='mbr-forgot-link']").click()

time.sleep(2)
inputt= driver.find_element_by_id("username")
time.sleep(2)
buttonn= driver.find_element_by_xpath("//*[@id='yid-challenge']/form/div[2]/button")

counter=0

nonumber= open("nonumber.txt","w")

while counter != len(list):
    inputt.send_keys(list[counter])
    time.sleep(1)
    buttonn.click()
    if len(driver.find_elements_by_css_selector("p[data-error]")) > 0 :
        inputt.clear()
        nonumber.write(list[counter])
        nonumber.close()
    counter=counter+1
```

here is the error it says button not clickable but in first run it works iam not sure is the problem in button or input area

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\Users\ramhelsinki\projects\slenium.py", line 54, in <module>
    inputt.send_keys(list[counter])
  File "C:\Users\ramhelsinki\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.9_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python39\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webelement.py", line 477, in send_keys
    self._execute(Command.SEND_KEYS_TO_ELEMENT,
  File "C:\Users\ramhelsinki\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.9_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python39\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webelement.py", line 633, in _execute
    return self._parent.execute(command, params)
  File "C:\Users\ramhelsinki\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.9_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python39\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 321, in execute
    self.error_handler.check_response(response)
  File "C:\Users\ramhelsinki\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.9_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python39\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\errorhandler.py", line 242, in check_response
    raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.StaleElementReferenceException: Message: stale element reference: element is not attached to the page document
  (Session info: chrome=91.0.4472.124)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Each time the web page is changed / refreshed all the web elements previously fetched by Selenium become irrelevant. This is what `stale element reference` exception comes for.
With your code, since page is refreshed in case of wrong input, I would advice fetching the elements again after each time the page is changed so the code will look like this:

```
time.sleep(2)

counter=0

nonumber= open("nonumber.txt","w")

while counter != len(list):
    inputt= driver.find_element_by_id("username")
    buttonn= driver.find_element_by_xpath("//button")

    inputt.send_keys(list[counter])
    time.sleep(1)
    buttonn.click()
    if len(driver.find_elements_by_css_selector("p[data-error]")) > 0 :
        inputt= driver.find_element_by_id("username")
        inputt.clear()
        nonumber.write(list[counter])
        nonumber.close()
    counter=counter+1
```